# How to link Relationship ObjectId with Activity ObjectId Primavera Web Service API

Tags: c#, primavera

We are trying to Read all relationships of an Activity using Primavera Web Service. Relationship and activity are different service , so i have both data in my hand but i am unable to link the data.

There is no link between Activity Service and Relationship Service can you please help me to solve the scenario.

`ActivityService.Activity[] FieldValues = oPBinder.ReadActivities(oFields);`

`Relationship[] response = RelationshipPortBinding.ReadRelationships(oRelations);`

The above 2 service method which i am trying to use to read activities and its relationships

Answer (score 1):

The successoractivityobjectid is the current activityobjectid. Try to implement filter based on successorprojectobjectid.